# Canvas drawImage scaling

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, resize, drawimage

I'm trying to scale an image proportionately to the canvas. I'm able to scale it with fixed width and height as so:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 100, 100)
```

But I only want to resize the width and have the height resize proportionately. Something like the following:

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 100, auto)
```

I've looked everywhere I can think of and haven't seen if this is possible.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```
context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, 100, 100 * imageObj.height / imageObj.width)
```

Comment: For best performance, make sure your image is saved with the correct width and height and preloaded. If that is not possible, you can fall back to the other answers below.

Answer (score 8):

@TechMaze's solution is quite good.

Here is the code after some corrections and the introduction of the `image.onload` event. `image.onload` is essential in order to avoid any kind of distortion.

```
function draw_canvas_image() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("image-holder-canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var imageObj = document.getElementById("myImageToDisplayOnCanvas");

  imageObj.onload = function() {
    var imgWidth = imageObj.naturalWidth;
    var screenWidth  = canvas.width;
    var scaleX = 1;
    if (imgWidth > screenWidth)
        scaleX = screenWidth/imgWidth;
    var imgHeight = imageObj.naturalHeight;
    var screenHeight = canvas.height;
    var scaleY = 1;
    if (imgHeight > screenHeight)
        scaleY = screenHeight/imgHeight;
    var scale = scaleY;
    if(scaleX < scaleY)
        scale = scaleX;
    if(scale < 1){
        imgHeight = imgHeight*scale;
        imgWidth = imgWidth*scale;          
    }

    canvas.height = imgHeight;
    canvas.width = imgWidth;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.naturalWidth, imageObj.naturalHeight, 0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to properly scale the picture as per the screen size, here is the code you can use:

```
var imgWidth = imageObj.naturalWidth;
var screenWidth  = $(window).width() - 20; 
var scaleX = 1;
if (imageWdith > screenWdith)
  scaleX = screenWidth/imgWidth;
var imgHeight = imageObj.naturalHeight;
var screenHeight = $(window).height() - canvas.offsetTop-10;
var scaleY = 1;
if (imgHeight > screenHeight)
  scaleY = screenHeight/imgHeight;
var scale = scaleY;
if(scaleX < scaleY)
  scale = scaleX;
if(scale < 1){
  imgHeight = imgHeight*scale;
  imgWidth = imgWidth*scale;      
}
canvas.height = imgHeight;
canvas.width = imgWidth;
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.naturalWidth, imageObj.naturalHeight, 0,0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

If you are not using jQuery, replace `$(window).width` with the appropriate equivalent option.